# Give someone a tip ....(that is "tip someone ")

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

Is it natural to say:

> She gave the waitress a tip of $10.

Or

> She gave the waitress a $10 tip.

Do both of them sound natural. I guess the second sentence sounds natural, whereas the first one doesn't.  What do you think? Do they sound natural as this one: **she tipped the waitress $10.**

Comment: As you surmise, the second sentence is the more likely. It's just easier off the tongue. Your final suggestion is also idiomatic. The first is fine; it just takes more effort.

Comment: @RonaldSole - I think this is an interesting question, though, because we use that construct with other phrases. For example: _she gave the waitress a bite of food; she gave the waitress a piece of her mind; she gave the waitress a cup of coffee; she gave the waitress a work of art_. For some reason, though, it sounds unusual with *...a tip of ten dollars.*

Answer (score 2):

> She gave the waitress a $10 tip.
>    She tipped the waitress $10.

Both of those sound natural and idiomatic to my ear

> She gave the waitress a tip of $10.

That sounds awkwardly structured to me. I wouldn't go so far as to call it "ungrammatical," but I don't think you'd hear it nearly as often as the other two.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20tip%20of%20%24%2010%2Ca%20%24%2010%20tip&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20%24%2010%20tip%3B%2Cc0) only the second variant is found in printed works.